# How to bringback an object to its original position after rotation in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, mouseevent, rotatetransform

I have created a project where a cube is rotated when we touch on it. I want the cube to return back to its original position when the user stops touching the cube. Below I have added the source code of rotating a cube:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]

public class dr : MonoBehaviour 
{

    #region ROTATE
    private float _sensitivity = 1f;
    private Vector3 _mouseReference;
    private Vector3 _mouseOffset;
    private Vector3 _rotation = Vector3.zero;
    private bool _isRotating;


    #endregion

    void Update()
    {
        if(_isRotating)
        {
            // offset
            _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference); // apply rotation
            _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity; // rotate
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(_rotation); // store new mouse position
            _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
        }

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = true;

        // store mouse position
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = false;
    }

}
```

edited code:-
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]

public class pt : MonoBehaviour 
{

```
#region ROTATE
private float _sensitivity = 1f;
private Vector3 _mouseReference;
private Vector3 _mouseOffset;
private Vector3 _rotation = Vector3.zero;
private bool _isRotating;
private Quaternion original;


#endregion
void start(){
    original = transform.rotation;
}

void Update()
{
    if(_isRotating)
    {
        // offset
        _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference); // apply rotation
        _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity; // rotate
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(_rotation); // store new mouse position
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }

}

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    // rotating flag
    _isRotating = true;

    // store mouse position
    _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
}

public void OnMouseUp()
{
    // rotating flag
    _isRotating = false;
    transform.rotation = original;
}
```

}

"im trying to rotate a 3d model of a sofa and return to its starting rotation.but if i used this code " **whenever if i stopped touching the sofa , it turns to **backside** of sofa"**
 i want it to return to initial rotation.[u can see initally this is how the sofa looks like and if i stopped touching it returns to its backside of sofa. i want it to return to its front side again if i stopped rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9pE2.png)

Comment: If you want `Mukesh` to answer your question, then as it personally, why are you posting here?

Comment: You want it to instantly return back to its original position, or you want it to rotate back to its original position?

Comment: @aishwariya I'd appreciate if you could avoid using caps lock. There is no purpose to it, and it won't help you for anything. Could you please also elaborate on what exactly you are calling the "original position"? Do you mean the **position** of your object, or the original **rotation** of your object? Because when I am reading your question, it seems more that you are talking about the original rotation of your object there.

Comment: @aishwariya You are being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349620/how-to-behave-with-a-user-repeatedly-pinging-me-in-comments) if you're interesetd to know

Comment: @luska    here the cube is placed in a particular position and the position is fixed.just only the cube rotates I want it to come to its original rotation.please do Reply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want the cube to return back to its original position when the user
>   stopped touching the cube

I can't exactly tell which part of this you are struggling with but you can simply get the position of the GameObject in  the `Start` or `Awake` function then set the `transform.position` to that value when `OnMouseUp` is called.

```
private Vector3 originalPos;

void Start()
{
  //Get the original position
  originalPos = transform.position;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    _isRotating = false;
    //Reset GameObject to the original position
    transform.position = originalPos;
}
```

**EDIT:**

For rotation, it is also the-same thing. Just use `Quaternion` and `transform.rotation` instead of `Vector3` and `transform.position`.

```
private Quaternion originalPos;

void Start()
{
  //Get the original rotation
  originalPos = transform.rotation;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    _isRotating = false;
    //Reset GameObject to the original rotation
    transform.rotation = originalPos;
}
```

You still have to incorporate that into the original code from your answer. If this is something you can't do then consider watching Unity's scripting tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting).

Comment: There is  nothing complicated here. If it doesn't work and you can't explain which part does not work then wait for "Saini Mukesh Saini" to provide a working answer.

Comment: No and no. You will not learn by doing that. Take the code from your **original** question then mix it with the code from my answer. **You have not done that**. You have to do that. Update the code in the edit with the result of what I just said.